# limit bounds of tuning parameters for linear regression in scikit-learn or statsmodels

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, statsmodels

Is it possible to limit the bounds of tuning parameters for linear regression in scikit-learn or statsmodels, e.g. in statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS or sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression?

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

**EDIT**:

---

scipy 0.17 includes scipy.optimize.leastsq with bound constraints:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares

Ideally what I'm looking is to minimize objective error function and also minimize the change of tuning multiplier parameters from default value of 1.0. This is likely part of objective function.

Note that this is the list of options that worked for my box bounds:

```
method='trf' or 'dogbox'
loss='cauchy'
f_scale=1e-5 to 1e-2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "limit the bounds of tuning parameters".

- If you'd like the result components to lie in pre-specified ranges, you could try [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html), which solves

  > minimize F(x) = 0.5 * sum(rho(f_i(x)**2), i = 0, ..., m - 1)
  >   subject to lb <= x <= ub
- If you're concerned about the result components being too large in magnitude due to colinearity, you can try [`sklearn.linear_model.Ridge`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html) (or one of the other regularized linear regressors there).

Comment: is it possible to combine ridge regression with bound constraints?

Comment: When replacing linear regression, the scipy method linear least squares should be sufficient https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html#scipy.optimize.lsq_linear