# How to use statsmodels linear regression with positive fit values?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to a linear regression with POSITIVE fitting value. I somehow cant do it with statsmodels. I can do it with scikit learns, but I also need standard deviation values and sklearn does not do that. How can I achieve this?

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = np.array([4, 5, 3])

ols = sm.OLS(b, a.T)
res = ols.fit()
res.summary()
```

Gives :

```
    coef    std err t   P>|t|   [0.025  0.975]
x1  -2.1667 1.462   -1.481  0.378   -20.749 16.416
x2  1.6667  0.624   2.673   0.228   -6.257  9.590
```

But as I said, I want both x1 and x2 to be positive

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411603/limit-bounds-of-tuning-parameters-for-linear-regression-in-scikit-learn-or-stats) gives some insight. [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) is also a good option.

Comment: Getting standard errors for parameter estimates under (possibly binding) inequality constraints is difficult https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1211 Not yet available in statsmodels.